# XMPP connection fails using perl client and ejabberd/ecs container

Tags: xml, perl, xmpp, tls1.2, ejabberd

I am using the docker-ejabberd/ecs container as a XMPP server and the [Net::XMPP perl client](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::XMPP) My ejabberd.yml looks like this:

```
hosts:
  - jabber-gw.foobar.me

loglevel: debug

ca_file: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

acme:
  ca_url: https://ca.foobar.local:8000/acme/acme/directory
  auto: false
  cert_type: rsa

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "0.0.0.0"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 65536
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5223
    ip: "0.0.0.0"
    tls: true
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "0.0.0.0"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 65536

  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "0.0.0.0"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /api: mod_http_api
      /bosh: mod_bosh
      /captcha: ejabberd_captcha
      /upload: mod_http_upload
      /ws: ejabberd_http_ws
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "0.0.0.0"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /.well-known/acme-challenge: ejabberd_acme
  -
    port: 3478
    ip: "0.0.0.0"
    transport: udp
    module: ejabberd_stun
    use_turn: true
    ## The server's public IPv4 address:
    # turn_ipv4_address: "203.0.113.3"
    ## The server's public IPv6 address:
    # turn_ipv6_address: "2001:db8::3"
  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "0.0.0.0"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000

s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
```

My ejabberd client perl code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::XMPP qw( Client );

if ($#ARGV < 4)
{
    print "\nperl client.pl <server> <port> <username> <password> <resource> \n\n";
    exit(0);
}

my $server = $ARGV[0];
my $port = $ARGV[1];
my $username = $ARGV[2];
my $password = $ARGV[3];
my $resource = $ARGV[4];


$SIG{HUP} = \&Stop;
$SIG{KILL} = \&Stop;
$SIG{TERM} = \&Stop;
$SIG{INT} = \&Stop;

my $Connection = new Net::XMPP::Client(
                                debug => "stdout",
                                debuglevel  => 2
                                );

$Connection->SetCallBacks(message=>\&InMessage,
                          presence=>\&InPresence,
                          iq=>\&InIQ);

my $status = $Connection->Connect(hostname=>$server,
                                  port=>$port,
                                  tls=>1,
                                  srv=>"jabber-gw.foobar.me",
                                  ssl_ca_path=>"/etc/ssl/certs/"
                                );

if (!(defined($status)))
{
    print "ERROR:  Jabber server is down or connection was not allowed.\n";
    print "        ($!)\n";
    exit(0);
}

my @result = $Connection->AuthSend(username=>$username,
                                   password=>$password,
                                   resource=>$resource);

if ($result[0] ne "ok")
{
    print "ERROR: Authorization failed: $result[0] - $result[1]\n";
    exit(0);
}

print "Logged in to $server:$port...\n";

$Connection->RosterGet();

print "Getting Roster to tell server to send presence info...\n";

$Connection->PresenceSend();

print "Sending presence to tell world that we are logged in...\n";

while(defined($Connection->Process())) { }

print "ERROR: The connection was killed...\n";

exit(0);


sub Stop
{
    print "Exiting...\n";
    $Connection->Disconnect();
    exit(0);
}
```

> I can successfully obtain an ACME cert for my host, then add the ca root cert to the clients ssl_ca_path. I then register the client on the server with ejabberdclt instructions. When i try to connect the client to the server, i see **Nodeprep failed **in the server logs:

```
2022-11-28 05:35:44.211915+00:00 [info] (<0.974.0>) Accepted connection 192.168.11.19:44198 -> 192.168.32.4:5222
2022-11-28 05:35:44.212589+00:00 [notice] (tcp|<0.974.0>) Received XML on stream = <<"<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream version='1.0' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' xmlns='jabber:client' to='jabber-gw.foobar.me' from='OMVonHP.foobar.me' xml:lang='en' >">>
..
omitted
..
2022-11-28 05:35:44.310551+00:00 [notice] (tls|<0.974.0>) Received XML on stream = <<"<response xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'></response>">>
2022-11-28 05:35:44.310855+00:00 [debug] Running hook c2s_handle_recv: mod_stream_mgmt:c2s_handle_recv/3
2022-11-28 05:35:44.311055+00:00 [debug] Running hook c2s_auth_result: ejabberd_c2s:process_auth_result/3
2022-11-28 05:35:44.311249+00:00 [warning] (tls|<0.974.0>) Failed c2s DIGEST-MD5 authentication from 192.168.11.19: Nodeprep failed
2022-11-28 05:35:44.311422+00:00 [debug] Running hook c2s_auth_result: mod_fail2ban:c2s_auth_result/3
2022-11-28 05:35:44.311667+00:00 [notice] (tls|<0.974.0>) Send XML on stream = <<"<failure xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><not-authorized/><text xml:lang='en'>Nodeprep failed</text></failure>">>
2022-11-28 05:35:44.311953+00:00 [debug] Running hook c2s_handle_send: mod_push:c2s_stanza/3
2022-11-28 05:35:44.314781+00:00 [debug] Running hook c2s_terminated: mod_pubsub:on_user_offline/2
2022-11-28 05:35:44.315136+00:00 [debug] Running hook c2s_terminated: ejabberd_c2s:process_terminated/2
2022-11-28 05:35:44.315395+00:00 [notice] (tls|<0.974.0>) Send XML on stream = <<"</stream:stream>">>
```

and in the client logs:

```
DMyODMwZg==)
XML::Stream: Node: _handle_close: sid(6607014926489030516) sax(XML::Stream::Parser=HASH(0x55e0c0b3e700)) tag(challenge)
XML::Stream: Node: _handle_close: check( 0 )
XML::Stream: Node: _handle_close: check2( -1 )
XML::Stream: Send: (<response xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'></response>)
XML::Stream: Process: block(0)
XMPP::Conn: AuthSASL: haven't authed yet... let's wait.
XMPP::Conn: Process: timeout(1)
XML::Stream: Read: buff(<failure xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><not-authorized/><text xml:lang='en'>Nodeprep failed</text></failure>)

XMPP::Conn: AuthSASL: Authentication failed.
ERROR: Authorization failed: error - not-authorized
```

I cant find anywhere what Nodeprep failed means? Would appreciate some help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it's taken me two and a half days but i have a workaround. I've worked out it's failing whilst the client is using DIGEST-MD5 sasl authentication mechanism (likely cos the NET::XMPP library hasn't been refreshed in many years). I discovered [here](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/toplevel/#disable-sasl-mechanisms) that you can force the server to disable sasl mechanisms offered to the client, so i added:

```
disable_sasl_mechanisms: DIGEST-MD5
```

to my ejabberd.yml file which forced plain auth - not ideal but in my case i am using TLS and certs so i can live with it. With plain auth my client connects fine without Nodeprep failures.

Answer (score 1):

nodeprep, node preparation, it parses the username to see if it satisfies the characters requirements by XMPP: not using invalid characters like " & ' / : < > @

Did you try to register an account with latin characters like "admin" or "lukewarms", or did it include more complex or uncommon characters?

I installed ejabberd 21.12 from souce, disabled starttls because I don't have a valid certificate, and your script works correctly:

```
ejabberdctl register admin localhost asd
...
./client.perl localhost 5222 admin asd Perr
...
```

ejabberd log file shows:

```
2022-11-28 16:47:15.776517+01:00 [info] (<0.1263.0>)
 Accepted connection [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:60816 -> [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:5222
2022-11-28 16:47:15.847908+01:00 [info] (tcp|<0.1263.0>)
 Accepted c2s PLAIN authentication for admin@localhost
 by mnesia backend from ::ffff:127.0.0.1
2022-11-28 16:47:15.878782+01:00 [info] (tcp|<0.1263.0>)
 Opened c2s session for admin@localhost/Perr
2022-11-28 16:47:15.928367+01:00 [info] (tcp|<0.1263.0>)
 Closing c2s session for admin@localhost/Perr:
 Connection failed: connection closed
```

Some ideas for you to try:

A) Try registering and logging in an account with simple username, like "abcd"

B) Try logging in with a well-known and tested XMPP client, like Gajim, Psi, Conversations, ...

C) Try disabling starttls in the 5222 port, to check if there's some problem there.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
I have tried option a) with "abcd" with no change to the result.
I have tried option b) using yaxim on my phone and it works fine.
i have tried option c) with no change to the perl client result (yaxim on my phone confirmed not TLS)
So it seems there is an issue with my  perl client/script. 
I am running the client on the container host and resolving the fqdn "jabber-gw.foobar.me" on my gateway to point back to the host where port 5222 is mapped to the container.. but given the log entries show the connection is accepted, this shouldnt be an issue

Comment: did you run ejabberd in a container when you tired it? I seem to be hitting the same issue when i repeat your test just running it as localhost with starttls disabled on port 5222. Client log:
`XML::Stream: Connect: Got a connection
1</mechanism><mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism></mechanisms><register 
XMPP::Conn: Connect: connection made
mechanism='DIGEST-MD5'></auth>)
authorized/><text xml:lang='en'>Nodeprep failed</text></failure>)
XMPP::Conn: AuthSASL: Authentication failed.
ERROR: Authorization failed: error - not-authorized`